# Thread Safe Resque Workers in JRuby when deployed as WAR

Tags: java, tomcat, rake, jruby, resque

Currently we are using Resque in JRuby and we use two ways of starting a Worker when developing.

- Using Rake:

```
QUEUE=* jruby -J-cp /path/to/library -S rake environment resque:work
```

- Programmatically, initialized through a Sinatra Rack App (or whatever), eventually calling a class with:

```
def start
   @worker = Resque::Worker.new(@queues)
   @worker.verbose = @vervose
   @worker.work(@interval)
end

def stop
   @worker.try(:shutdown)
end
```

Although both these solutions are acceptable for us in development. I am concern about how this would work when deployed to Tomcat for example.

In Ruby normally, you would spawn or demonize workers, then use a monitoring tool to watch the pid's.

Would it make sense to start the Workers programmatically when deployed? I'm wondering if it starts a new thread in java or clutters the jruby process, if not should I use, yet another scheduling library like quartz to start a worker? or a rake task that launches at deploy task?

I could create a Worker model and then have that keep track of the workers in a db, but that doesn't make sense to me.

Any help or knowledge will be appreciated.

Thank You.

Refs:

https://github.com/defunkt/resque

http://rubydoc.info/github/defunkt/resque/master/Resque/

http://blog.thomasmango.com/post/636319317/resque-in-production

https://gist.github.com/486161

Answer (score 0):

Using `rake resque:work` will boot your Rails environment and start one worker, which polls for a job, forks itself into a (sub-)worker process, processes that job and then quits.

If you want to run multiple workers then use the `COUNT` variable:

`QUEUE=* COUNT=5 jruby -J-cp /path/to/library -S rake environment resque:work`

What aspect of this would be deployed to Tomcat? This is all command line.

Comment: How would you make this work if your JRuby/Rails app was deployed via a WAR file into Tomcat? Do I have to deploy 2 Tomcats, one for the "rails server" and one for the "rake environment resque:work"? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

More than a year late but I think the answer you were looking for is to run Resque workers along side your application in (native) Java threads. Since you're using JRuby::Rack the answer is [JRuby::Rack::Worker](https://github.com/kares/jruby-rack-worker). Add this to your *web.xml* :

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>jruby.worker</param-name>
  <param-value>resque</param-value>
</context-param>
<!--
<context-param>
  <param-name>QUEUES</param-name>
  <param-value>mails,posts</param-value>
</context-param>-->

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.kares.jruby.rack.WorkerContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

If you're warbling there's a *web.xml.erb* sample https://github.com/kares/jruby-rack-worker just create a *config/web.xml.erb* file and copy the content to it ... If you happen to use Trinidad there's an [extension](https://github.com/kares/trinidad_worker_extension) built on top of it (so you do not need to setup a web.xml and copy the .jar file).